# Cisco Wifi phones unregistration from CUCME

Tags: cisco, wireless

I have:

- two Cisco Wifi access points AIR-AP1832I-E-K9 (AP1 and AP2)
- and two Cisco wireless phones CP-8821 (P1 and P2).

***Phone P1***

- P1 usually connects to AP1 and never connects to AP2 except if it is roaming.
- This is because it clearly is closer to AP1 than AP2 when it is in the room where its "docking station" is.

***Phone P2***

- P2 is in a room which is quasi equally distant from AP1 and AP2.
- I notice that it regularly disconnects from CUCME.

  *Oct 15 13:16:41.865 CET: VOICE REGISTER POOL-2 has unregistered. Name:SEP501CB03A593E  IP:192.168.4.7  DeviceType:Phone
- It never seems to loose the Wifi signal since there always are 2/4 or 3/4 bars on the Wifi pictogram.
- It connects to AP2, then disconnects and connects to AP1 and then disconnects. (But I haven't noticed a specific pattern.)
  [image]
  In the image above, even if each phone is a client either for AP1 or AP2, P2 doesn't work because is has unregistered from CUCME.

What can I do to stabilize P2 (apart from moving it to another room)?

Thank you and best regards.

Comment: There is no standard way for a client to select the AP to associate with, so this is a proprietary function built in to the Cisco phones or any wireless client. I would start with checking the RSSI, and SNR in the room with P2, but there are a lot of other variables. For example, your AP2 is using DFS channels so Radar events could be causing channel changes. Is the roaming correlated with the CUCME disassociation?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. No, the CUCME disassociation is not correlated with the roaming. CUCME disassociation happens even if P2 is not moving from its room.

Comment: If your graphic is correct, your AP2 is using DFS channels, which will change any time it detects a radar event. I would switch to a non-DFS channel that is no more than 40MHz wide.